# aov vs anova/lm

Tags: r, regression

I'm trying to understand how `aov` relates to `lm`, and [this question and its answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15062/how-is-an-anova-calculated-for-a-repeated-measures-design-aov-vs-lm-in-r) have been very helpful. However, I'm finding some differences between the F values and p values between the `aov` and `anova` calls:

```r
    set.seed(1)
    DF <- data.frame(participant=factor(1:5), A.1=rnorm(5, 50, 
        20), A.2=rnorm(5, 100, 20), B.1=rnorm(5, 20, 20), 
        B.2=rnorm(5, 50, 20))
    
    conditions <- names(DF)[ names(DF) != "participant" ]
    
    dfL <- reshape(DF, direction="long", varying=conditions, 
          v.names="value", idvar="participant", times=conditions, 
          timevar="group")
    
    dfL$factor1 <- factor( rep(c("A", "B"), each=10) )
dfL$factor2 <- factor( rep(c(1, 2), each=5) )
    
    names(dfL) <- c("id", "group", "DV", "IV1", "IV2")
```

`aov` output:

```r
    my.aov <- aov(DV ~ IV1*IV2 + Error(id / (IV1*IV2)), dfL)
    summary(my.aov)
        Error: id:IV1
                  Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
        IV1        1   7094    7094   11.79 0.0264 *
        Residuals  4   2406     602
```

`anova` output:

```r
    anova(lm(DV ~ id, dfL), lm(DV ~ id+IV1, dfL))
    
    Model 1: DV ~ id
    Model 2: DV ~ id + IV1
      Res.Df   RSS Df Sum of Sq      F  Pr(>F)  
    1     15 23011                              
    2     14 15917  1    7094.1 6.2397 0.02557 *
```

How can I extract the same information (F values, p values) that `aov` outputs from `lm`?

Comment: The model described in the `aov` isn't the same as that in the `lm`. ...  Because your design is balanced, the following will return the same results: `my.aov <- aov(DV ~ IV1*IV2, dfL); summary(my.aov); model = lm(DV ~ IV1*IV2, dfL); anova(model)`. For unbalanced designs, and for additional options with an `lm` object, you might use `car::Anova`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @SalMangiafico. If I understood the answer I linked to in my question, I think the `anova(lm)` is equivalent to the `aov` at least in terms of how the sum of squares are calculated (and are actually identical as I show for effect IV1 in my question). What I'm asking is how can I get the same F and p values as well? Your suggestion `model = lm(DV ~ IV1*IV2, dfL); anova(model)` still gives different F and p values (eg, for `IV1` `aov` gives me F=11.79 but `anova(model)` gives me F=18.50)

Comment: Well, since you've specified a error term to use in your `aov()`, it won't translate to a default anova with `lm()`.  Probably, you would formulate a mixed-effects model with `lmer` or `lme`, but I don't know offhand what model would be equivalent to what you are trying to do with your `aov`.  There might be a way to specify error terms to be used in the anova table in `anova` or `car::Anova`, but I don't know.